# Get Google Plus Url Share Count

Tags: google-plus, share

I have read tons of posts about how to do this and they all say to use:

```
gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ')
gapi.client.rpcRequest('pos.plusones.get', 'v1', {
   nolog: true,
   id: "http://www.google.com/",
   source: "widget",
   userId: "@viewer",
   groupId: "@self"
}).execute(function(resp) {
   console.log('count:', resp.result.metadata.globalCounts.count)
});
```

rpcRequest no longer appears to be supported the accepted call is to .request but when using pos.plusone.get it just 404's.  Is there another URL to use? Is this no longer possible.  What Gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This still works for me:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
var params = {
  nolog: true,
  id: "http://www.google.com/",
  source: "widget",
  userId: "@viewer",
  groupId: "@self"
};

gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ')
gapi.client.rpcRequest('pos.plusones.get', 'v1', params).execute(function(resp) {
  console.log('count:', resp.result.metadata.globalCounts.count)
});
```

JSF: http://jsfiddle.net/rs7z5aLc/

Also, you will get the following warning:

```
gapi.client.rpcRequest is deprecated. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs
```

So it might be just a matter of time.

Comment: Yes I have gotten this result as well, I guess I was looking to see if there is a  new method to get this that won't potentially go away in a month.  Also am i supposed to use the developer API key in my production App? Why doesn't my API Key work.  When i use my own API Key I don't have an option to use rpcRequest.

Comment: Apparently the API only works for the Dev Key above at this point.. I actually found references to this as late as 2011.. so this API was never public really I believe.